# How to disable SSL certificate checks in Java project?

Tags: java, maven, ssl

I'm getting this error all the time while trying to connect to a remote machine's API and I certainly do not need to check it's certificate when connecting.

```
ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I get rid of this validation? I've set these variables on my JVM:

```
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

I'm using Java 17, with Maven and using Eclipse Spring Tool Suite 4.

Comment: Download the certificate and add it to your jvm keystore. Disabling the ssl check is not a good (or a very bad) idea

Comment: I've done it already, but as I said, the API is in a remote machine so it will always give this error, also this is for testing, no need of certifications for now

Comment: *the API is in a remote machine so it will always give this error* isn't that (virtually) *always* the case? Anyway, [loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) of stuff on this

Comment: Based on that `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` are you really using somewhere WAGON? How does your pom file look like?

Answer (score -1):

Do not disable SSL checks.
You have to import the whole certificate-chain into your keystore.

Your program then need to add the truststore properties:

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","clientTrustStore.key");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","qwerty");

[Oracle Running the client with SSL/TLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/cadminsslclient.html)

[Difference between Key and Trust-Store](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference)